# Extract public.key

Tags: java, ssl, https, openssl, keytool

We have a situation here which we tried to fix using two different ways

A (encrypts data with public.key ) ---sends data to---> B (decrypts with private.key)

We don't have control over application A and we have to add another application C which will perform the same task as B

1) So we created a keystore for C using keytool now we want to export the public.key file from that keystore , is there a way to do that ?

2) We generated Private.key , Public.key using OPEN SSL and created CSR with SAN

```
req -new -key \..\..\..\private.key -sha256 -nodes -subj '/C=IN/ST=test/L=test/O=test/OU=test/CN=localhost/emailAddress=xxx@xxx.com/subjectAltName=IP.1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' -out ..\..\..\xyz.csr
```

and generated Certificate and Keystore 
but even after adding the SAN it is throwing

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1338)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:568)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
... 63 more
```

So I am not able to make it work this way as well

Can anyone suggest something here on either ways

Answer (score 0):

Your generated certificate is *probably* missing the "*X509v3 Subject Alternative Name*" extension.

You can verify this using command:

```
openssl req -in xyz.csr -text
```

The output should contain something like this:

> ```
>     Requested Extensions:
>         X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
>             IP Address:...
> ```

If it does not, then you might find e.g. [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line) useful.

Comment: Hi VLP , The output is below , it contains the entry just like you mentioned                                                                                           Requested Extensions:X509v3 Basic Constraints:
CA:FALSE
X509v3 Key Usage:
Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
 DNS:localhost, IP Address:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: I focused on the fact, that this exception is caused by missing extension "Subject Alternative Name" in the server certificate (to be honest your question is not very clear about what and when is throwing this exception -- I assume it is thrown by application A when it is connecting to application C...could you please confirm that and update your question?). You can check the server certificate content by issuing a command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <serverAddress>:<serverPort> </dev/null | openssl x509 -text` (on linux). On windows you would probably need to execute....ctd.

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <serverAddress>:<serverPort>` first and then take the parts marked with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`, put them into file (do include the lines in the file) and parse this file using `openssl x509 -in <theFile> -text`.